# error: constexpr variable 'nOff' must be initialized by a constant expression

Tags: c++

clang compile fail, but not g++

```
/Users/xx/xxx/xxxx/common/src/memorychunkpn.hpp:438:28: error: constexpr variable 'nOff' must be initialized by a constant expression
            constexpr auto nOff = (size_t)(uintptr_t)(&((*((InnMemoryChunk *)(0))).Data[0]));
```

`InnMemoryChunk`:

```
  typedef struct _InnMemoryChunk{
  bool In;            // this to indicate the chunk is allocated in the memory pool
                      // actually we can compare pointer range to decide

  size_t NodeID;      // node in its memory pool, use it for offset calculation
  size_t PoolID;      //
  size_t BranchID;    //

  uint8_t Data[4];    // offset to the data field, size is always ok
}InnMemoryChunk;
```

Anyone could help please?

Comment: That's undefined behavior anyways. Use the standard `offsetof`.

Comment: You mean replacing `size_t` with `offsetof` ?

Comment: No, I mean replacing that entire pointer mess with `offsetof`. Check out the docs, it's quite straight forward.

Comment: It's c++14 here, I included `cstddef` header, but still no offsetof found.

Comment: Should exist in said header. MCVE (in a new question) or it didn't happen.

Comment: Also OT: `_InnMemoryChunk` is an implementation reserved identifier, you cannot use it.

Comment: Yeah, It worked, `offsetof(InnMemoryChunk, Data)` pretty straightforward